# parent class opponent method will inherited by subclasses.full question details are in comments

Tags: python-3.x

**Write another method in the parent class that will be inherited by the subclasses.Call it opponent. It should return which type of pokemon current type is weak and strong against, as  tuple.
Grass is weak against Fire and strong against Water
Ghost is weak against Dark and strong against Psychic
Fire is weak against Water and strong against Grass
Flying is weak against Electric and strong against Fighting
.For example, if the p_type of the subclass is 'Grass', .opponent() should return the tuple ('Fire', 'Water')**

```
class Pokemon():
    attack = 12
    defense = 10
    health = 15
    p_type = "Normal"

    def __init__(self, name,level = 5):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.weak = "Normal"
        self.strong = "Normal"

    def train(self):
        self.update()
        self.attack_up()
        self.defense_up()
        self.health_up()
        self.level = self.level + 1
        if self.level%self.evolve == 0:
            return self.level, "Evolved!"
        else:
            return self.level

    def attack_up(self):
        self.attack = self.attack + self.attack_boost
        return self.attack
    def defense_up(self):
        self.defense = self.defense + self.defense_boost
        return self.defense

    def health_up(self):
        self.health = self.health + self.health_boost
        return self.health

    def update(self):
        self.health_boost = 5
        self.attack_boost = 3
        self.defense_boost = 2
        self.evolve = 10

    def __str__(self):
        self.update()
        return "Pokemon name: {}, Type: {}, Level: {}".format(self.name, self.p_type, self.level)

    def opponent(self, p_type):
    if self.ptype == "Grass":
        return ("Fire", "Water")
    elif self.p_type == "Ghost":
        return ("Dark","Psychic")
    elif self.p_type == "Fire":
        return ("Water","Grass")
    else :
        return ("Electric","Fighting")




class Grass_Pokemon(Pokemon):
    attack = 15
    defense = 14
    health = 12
    p_type = "Grass"

    def update(self):
        self.health_boost = 6
        self.attack_boost = 2
        self.defense_boost = 3
        self.evolve = 12



class Ghost_Pokemon(Pokemon):
    p_type = "Ghost"

    def update(self):
        self.health_boost = 3
        self.attack_boost = 4
        self.defense_boost = 3

    def opponent(self):
    if self.p_type == "Ghost":
        return ("Dark", "Psychic")

class Fire_Pokemon(Pokemon):
    p_type = "Fire"



class Flying_Pokemon(Pokemon):
    p_type = "Flying"
```

Comment: You can write a test that confirm what you expect, then you implement the method. If you have an error or it doesn't work put an example of what's not working and your opponent() function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using a dictionary that contains strengths and weaknesses,

```
def opponent(self):

    op = {'Grass': ['Fire', 'Water'], 'Ghost': ['Dark', 'Psychic'], 'Fire':['Water', 'Grass'], 'Flying': ['Electric', 'Fighting']}

    return tuple(op[self.p_type])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I get it


    class Pokemon():
        attack = 12
        defense = 10
        health = 15
        p_type = "Normal"

        def __init__(self, name,level = 5):
            self.name = name
            self.level = level
            self.weak = "Normal"
            self.strong = "Normal"

        def train(self):
            self.update()
            self.attack_up()
            self.defense_up()
            self.health_up()
            self.level = self.level + 1
            if self.level%self.evolve == 0:
                return self.level, "Evolved!"
            else:
                return self.level

        def attack_up(self):
            self.attack = self.attack + self.attack_boost
            return self.attack
        def defense_up(self):
            self.defense = self.defense + self.defense_boost
            return self.defense

        def health_up(self):
            self.health = self.health + self.health_boost
            return self.health

        def update(self):
            self.health_boost = 5
            self.attack_boost = 3
            self.defense_boost = 2
            self.evolve = 10

        def __str__(self):
            self.update()
            return "Pokemon name: {}, Type: {}, Level: {}".format(self.name, self.p_type, self.level)

        def opponent(self, p_type):
        if self.ptype == "Grass":
            return ("Fire", "Water")
        elif self.p_type == "Ghost":
            return ("Dark","Psychic")
        elif self.p_type == "Fire":
            return ("Water","Grass")
        else :
            return ("Electric","Fighting")

        def opponent(self,p_type):

        if self.p_type == "Grass":
            return ("Fire", "Water")
        elif self.p_type == "Ghost":
            return ("Dark", "Psychic")
        elif self.p_type == "Fire":
            return ("Water", "Grass")
        else :
            return ("Electric", "Fighting") 


    class Grass_Pokemon(Pokemon):
        attack = 15
        defense = 14
        health = 12
        p_type = "Grass"

        def update(self):
            self.health_boost = 6
            self.attack_boost = 2
            self.defense_boost = 3
            self.evolve = 12

        def opponent(self):
        if self.p_type == "Grass":
            return ("Fire", "Water")

    class Ghost_Pokemon(Pokemon):
        p_type = "Ghost"

        def update(self):
            self.health_boost = 3
            self.attack_boost = 4
            self.defense_boost = 3

        def opponent(self):
        if self.p_type == "Ghost":
            return ("Dark", "Psychic")

    class Fire_Pokemon(Pokemon):
        p_type = "Fire"

        def opponent(self):
        if self.p_type == "Fire":
            return ("Water", "Grass")


    class Flying_Pokemon(Pokemon):
        p_type = "Flying"

        def opponent(self):
        if self.p_type == "Flying":
            return ("Electric", "Fighting")
```